# Is it a bad practice to use a GET parameter (in URL) with no value?

Tags: php, url, get

I'm in a little argument with my boss about URLs using GET parameters without value. E.g.

`http://www.example.com/?logout`

I see this kind of link fairly often on the web, but of course, this doesn't mean it's a good thing. He fears that this is not standard and could lead to unexpected errors, so he'd rather like me to use something like:

`http://www.example.com/?logout=yes`

In my experience, I've never encountered any problem using empty parameters, and they sometimes make more sense to me (like in this case, where `?logout=no` wouldn't make any sense, so the value of "logout" is irrelevant and I would only test for the presence of the parameter server-side, not for its value). (It also looks cleaner.)

However I can't find confirmation that this kind of usage is actually valid and therefore really can't cause any problem ever.

Do you have any link about this?

Comment: As long as you're just using `isset($_GET['logout']);` and you're happy with that, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Exactly what I'm doing. :)

Comment: Link http://www.example.com/?logout redirected (301) to http://www.example.com/?logout=
So you should take SEO in mind.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

RFC 2396, "Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax", §3.4, "Query Component" is the authoritative source of information on the query string, and states:

> The query component is a string of information to be interpreted by
>      the resource.
>
> [...]
>
> Within a query component, the characters ";", "/", "?", ":", "@",
>      "&", "=", "+", ",", and "$" are reserved.

RFC 2616, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1", §3.2.2, "http URL", does not redefine this.

In short, the query string you give ("logout") is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for the precise reference. :-) Here is the direct link if anyone is interested: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#page-15 . Also relevant: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738#page-9 (mentioned in another answer).

Answer (score 7):

A value is not **required** for the key to have any effect. It doesn't make the URL any less valid either, the URL [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#page-9) does not list it as required part of the URL.

If you don't really need a value, it's just a matter of preference.

```
http://example.com/?logout
```

Is just as much a valid URL as

```
http://example.com/?logout=yes
```

All difference that it makes is that if you want to make sure that the "yes" bit was absolutely set, you can check for it's value. Like:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == "yes") {
    // Only proceed if the value is explicitly set to yes
```

If you just want to know if the `logout` key was set somewhere in the URL, it would suffice to just list the key with no value assigned to it. You can then check it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    // Continue regardless of what the value is set to (or if it's left empty)
```

Comment: Thanks. Browsing the link you give, I also found https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#page-15 which is mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly fine, and won't cause any error. Though, nowadays most frameworks are MVC based, so in the URL you need to mention a *controller* and an *action*, so it looks more like `/users/logout` (BTW, also StackOverflow uses that URL to log users out ;).

The statement that it *may cause errors* to me sounds like your applications manually access the raw `$_GET`, and I definitely think that building apps without a framework (which usually provides an MVC stack and a router/dispatcher) is the real dangerous thing here.

Comment: "real dangerous thing" as in "if you really must find something dangerous in your example", or as in "NEVER do this"?

Comment: The former :) Still, developing in plain PHP, or vanilla JS, or anyway using just a programming language without any library is not smart practice for obvious resons