# are empty parameters in a long url string acceptable practice

Tags: php, url

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194059/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-a-get-parameter-in-url-with-no-value) indicates that an empty parameter in a URL string isn't such a bad thing. But it only asks about one parameter. It may seem a silly extension of the question, but if I have a long list of parameters, is it still considered acceptable practice?

`www.web.com?id=123&last_purchase_id=&last_purchase_date=&is_buyer=false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are empty parameters in a long url string acceptable practice?

*Yes* and *No*.

Yes in the fact that even an *empty value* represents a *value*. That is the absence of a value. Use cases would be reset, default, or opt-out a parameter.

No in the fact that if empty parameters are required for your code to properly execute. Instead you should default those values in code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference to the server between empty parameters and the non-existence of parameters.

```
isset($_GET['last_purchase_id'])
```

would be true even for an empty `last_purchase_id`. Therefore, whether you send the server empty parameters is up to your server's current implementation.